# unchecking checkbox in knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

html

```
<input id="checkbox" name="claimcheckbox" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsclaimcheckboxSubscribe,visible: Authorization.IsclaimcheckboxAuthorized" />
```

Java Script

```
IsclaimcheckboxSubscribe = ko.observable();
IsclaimcheckboxSubscribe.subscribe(function (newvalue) {
    claimcheckboxSelection(newvalue);
});

function claimcheckboxSelection(newvalue) {
    if (newvalue) {
        if (claimcheckboxConfirmation()) {
            //Do something

        } else {
            do other thing

        }

    } else {}


    function claimcheckboxConfirmation() {
        var claimcheckboxvalue = confirm("Do you want to process?");
        //if yes
        if (claimcheckboxvalue) {
            return true;
        } else {
            //if no
            return false;

        }
    }
```

now the problem is when message confirmation

> Do you want to process?

there is YES and NO button, when I click YES then i want to uncheck the checkbox. I tried 
IsclaimcheckboxSubscribe(false);
but it did not work.

Please note that I am not using jquery. So I want to u by usingncheck the checkbox by using the knockout js.
Could anybody please help!

Comment: where is your applybindings call?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hH4Dy/ seems to work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be a couple issues here.

1. there is no model setup
2. there is no call to applybindings
3. claimcheckboxSelection is missing a `}`

I was able to get it working by creating a model and applying the knockout bindings on that model.

```
var model = (function (){
    var self = {};
    self.IsclaimcheckboxSubscribe = ko.observable();    
    self.IsclaimcheckboxSubscribe.subscribe(function (newvalue) {
        claimcheckboxSelection(newvalue);
    });
    return self;
})();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Then in the claimcheckboxselection method I was able to set the value as you expected with `model.IsclaimcheckboxSubscribe(false)`

```
function claimcheckboxSelection(newvalue) {
    if (newvalue) {
        if (claimcheckboxConfirmation()) {
            // Do Something
        } else {
            model.IsclaimcheckboxSubscribe(false);
        }

    } else {}
}
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/JfXQv/